# To retrieve the image path for drag drop picture in CQ5

Tags: image, dialog, widget, components, aem

i made an image drag drop widget, it's for page background to dynamically rend BG with drag dropped picture.
in my dialog , i have the widget name 'bgimage'
question is, how do i retrieve the path from the drag dropped picture, i wanna store the path into a string , so i can use it in   to rend page BG
here is part of the code:

```
<% 
    Image image = new Image(resource, "bgimage");
    image.setSelector(".img");

if(image.hasContent()){

%><img class="full-screen-bg" src="<%= image.getIconPath() %>" alt="" /><%


}
```

%>

that image.getIconPath(), only gives me the null value....so it doesnt work....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`Image#getSrc()`](https://dev.day.com/docs/en/cq/current/javadoc/com/day/cq/commons/ImageResource.html#getSrc%28%29) method:

```
<img class="full-screen-bg" src="<%= image.getSrc() %>" alt="" />
```

You don't need to set a custom selector.